# Create a Function 'find_port' which takes port id as input and returns the count of transportation

Tags: sql, oracle, hotfix

Create a Function named 'find_port' which takes port id(i.e, p_id) as input and returns the count of transportation(i.e, transportation_count') that could be made using that port.
Function name : find_port
Input Parameter : p_id in int
Output variable : transportation_count variable of type number
Design rules:

1. If is_rail of the given port id is 'True',then display the transportation_count as '1'.
2. If is_rail of the given port id is 'False',then display the transportation_count as '0'.
   (NOTE :Design rule is only for example.Calculate transportation count for is_rail,is_road & is_air.)
   Refer to the schema for port details.

Comment: So, what have you tried?  What table or tables are accessed?  Why did you use the `[hotfix]` tag?.  See [ask]. Who asked you to "Create a Function"?

Comment: Can you write code against tables for which you have no knowledge?  No?  Then don't expect others to do it for you. _Especially_ when it is obviously a homework assignment.